# Post an Image to twitter using VBScript via the public Twitter API

Tags: twitter, vbscript, asp-classic, twitter-oauth

Has anybody managed to post an image to twitter using VBScript?  There are two amazingly useful VBScript resources out there that Scott and Tim have made available:

http://scottdesapio.com/VBScriptOAuth/#disqus_thread

http://www.timacheson.com/Blog/2013/jun/asptwitter

Both of them work great with not a great deal of effort.  They connect and validate using oAuth and also both send/read tweets.  I am having no luck so far trying to use the Twitter's POST media/upload API:

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/media/upload

So of course it can be done, has anybody in the VBScript world done this?  Does anyone in any other world have any thoughts/advice?  So far all attempts to send multipart/form-data containing an image have failed.

Using Scott's library here is the baseline code to send a tweet.

```
Dim objOAuth : Set objOAuth = New cLibOAuth
If objOAuth.LoggedIn Then
   call fireTweet("The date/time is: " & Now())
Else
   Response.Status = RESPONSE_STATUS_403
End If


function fireTweet(theTweet)
    objOAuth.ConsumerKey = OAUTH_EXAMPLE_CONSUMER_KEY
    objOAuth.ConsumerSecret = OAUTH_EXAMPLE_CONSUMER_SECRET
    objOAuth.EndPoint = TWITTER_OAUTH_URL_UPDATE_STATUS
    objOAuth.Host = TWITTER_API_HOST
    objOAuth.RequestMethod = OAUTH_REQUEST_METHOD_POST
    objOAuth.UserAgent = TWITTER_APP_NAME 
    objOAuth.Parameters.Add "oauth_token", Session(OAUTH_TOKEN)
    objOAuth.Parameters.Add "oauth_token_secret", session(OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)
    objOAuth.Parameters.Add "status", Replace(theTweet, "&", "%26")
    objOAuth.Send()
    Dim strResponseText : strResponseText = objOAuth.ResponseText
    Dim strErrorCode : strErrorCode = objOAuth.ErrorCode
    If Not IsNull(strErrorCode) Then
        Response.Status = RESPONSE_STATUS_500
        Response.Write strErrorCode
    Else
        Response.ContentType = "text/html"
        Response.CharSet = "utf-8"
        Response.Write strResponseText
    End If
end function
Set objOAuth = Nothing
```

EDIT : I wish to point out that this post has already passed oAuth.  I though I had explained this and it was clear from the code (If objOAuth.LoggedIn Then).  Apologies if this was not clear

Comment: Some details of the failures, error codes, attempted code would be more useful then any of this. However the biggest hurdle I can see is oAuth, if you can crack that nut then the Twitter part should be plain sailing.

Comment: The oauth is the easy part. If you look at the code about it checks for this. Oauth is a collection of files and a library. The code above posts a tweet you need to have achieved authentication to do this of course. You can down load the oauth code from scots link I have posted

Comment: I think you may have miss-read or miss-understood.  This post is not about oAuth, this is what I called the easy part.  You raised oAuth, all I said was this is the easy part, its done.   This post is about sending an image using the twitter API via VBScript.  The code above is the code to send a tweet (as I have made clear , after oAuth hence the If objOAuth.LoggedIn in the code) attaching an inage to the tweet will be a variation to the above code.   What your down vote, I dont understand this?  Shall we move forward and try to solve this issue now?

Comment: You may think that but I'm speaking from experience - *"Uploading media with OAuth can be a bit tricky, so we’ve outlined some things to keep in mind as well as a working sample of how to use this endpoint here."* and *"Because the method uses multipart POST, OAuth is handled a little differently. "* both direct quotes from [Uploading Media Guide to Uploading Media](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/uploading-media).

Comment: Thank you for your input but your not really on-topic if I may say so.  This post is not about oAuth.  I guess I will say it one more time oAuth is handled in a process just before this.  I am not trying to oAuth and upload in the same call.  If you have 'experience' with the media/upload Twitter API call I am interested to hear about it?  And yes of course I am very familiar with the link you posted.

Comment: Maybe once you post what attempts you've actually made [so] is not here to do it for you. If you're having problems edit the question and post specifics, what is erroring?, what is the error you received?

Comment: My point is you think this has nothing to do with OAuth, but that is an assumption as far as I can see. All you have posted is code to send a tweet using an OAuth wrapper class. This is not the same as uploading / posting an image to twitter even though you have stated in the question *"I am having no luck so far trying to use the Twitter's POST media/upload API"*. If that is the case **post the code you have tried** and the errors you are receiving instead of us having to second guess you then be shot down for mentioning what you consider off topic.